Need to have Azure API management policy to verify custom token using certifcate. Can anyone tell me How to verify token using certifcate?
My c# code is working perfectly fine. I need to write below c# logic int apim policy. Some namespaces are not supported in Azure APIM. My requirement is to decode a token and check the token validity, signature by reading the certificate public key.
C# logic below
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Text;

namespace TokenValidation
{
    internal class Program
    {
        
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var token = "eyJBdXRoZW50aWNhdGlvblR5cGUiOiJCZWFyZXIiLCJOYW1lQ2xhaW1UeXBlIjoiaHR0cDovL3NjaGVtYXMueG1sc29hcC5vcmcvd3MvMjAwNS8bGFpbXMvbmFtZSIsIlJvbGVDbGFpbVR5cGUiOiJodHRwOi8vc2NoZW1hcy54bWxzb2FwLm9yZy93wiT3JpZ2luYWxJc3N1ZXIiOiJMT0NBTCBBVVRIT1JJVFkifV0sIlByb3BlcnRpZXMiOnsiRGljdGlvbmFyeSI6eyIuaXNzdWVkIjoiRnJpLCAyNiBKdWwgMjAyNCAxMDo1ODo1OSBHTVQiLCIuZXhwaXJlcyI6IkZyaSwgMjYgSnVsIDIwMjQgMTE6MTg6NTkgR01UIn19fQ<---->LsQakfrTMrKd-0iQAsEzs4snSGo7bqmSjjJiUXAomhAMFyJcHRI3yYFgMl_f9CCviV_T7d-VkMFN1g3V40qsqkjtneumkRJfg-T6JMg1RtehgaSBsHr5qncNeVqq6HbSNbW_A_v5NWD3dv4pK9AytetxNv4sm64BVebiag2YUMMWBhpeus-brF6j_-Ck6nIA0hCphGBj3DLNmt7iNlkkSg";

            var Separator = "<---->";
            X509Certificate2 _certificate;
            
            
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
            {
                throw new KeyNotFoundException("Token is empty");
            }
            var dataAndSign = token.Split(new[] { Separator }, StringSplitOptions.None);

            if (dataAndSign.Length != 2)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Token has invalid format");
            }

            var originalData = dataAndSign[0];
            var signature = dataAndSign[1];



            var originalDataSanitized = originalData
    .Replace('_', '/').Replace('-', '+');
            switch (originalData.Length % 4)
            {
                case 2: originalDataSanitized += "=="; break;
                case 3: originalDataSanitized += "="; break;
            }
            byte[] bytesToVerify = Convert.FromBase64String(originalDataSanitized);


            var signatureSanitized = signature
    .Replace('_', '/').Replace('-', '+');
            switch (signature.Length % 4)
            {
                case 2: signatureSanitized += "=="; break;
                case 3: signatureSanitized += "="; break;
            }
            byte[] signedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(signatureSanitized);


            var certResourcePath = "TokenValidation.Certificate.OAuthAuthorization.cer";
            using (var resource = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(certResourcePath))
            using (var reader = new BinaryReader(resource))
            {
                _certificate = new X509Certificate2(reader.ReadBytes((int)resource.Length));
            }

            var rsa = _certificate.GetRSAPublicKey();
            var rsaPublicKey = rsa.ToXmlString(false);

            var isValid = rsa.VerifyData(bytesToVerify, signedBytes, HashAlgorithmName.SHA1, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);
        }
    }
}
`

Below is my APIM Policy. I have written this till the decoded token. Like in the c# code above, I should read the certifcate, get the public key and verify the token.
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <set-variable name="api.NamedValue.corrigoKey" value="{{corrigo-public-key}}" />
        <set-variable name="api.isCorrigoTokenVerifed" value="@{
                    var corrigoToken = context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("Authorization","scheme param").Split(' ').Last();
       var Separator = "<---->";
                 
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(corrigoToken))
{
     return "false";
}
var dataAndSign = corrigoToken.Split(new[] { Separator }, StringSplitOptions.None);

if (dataAndSign.Length != 2)
{
     return "false";
}

var originalData = dataAndSign[0];
var signature = dataAndSign[1];

        var originalDataSanitized = originalData
.Replace('_', '/').Replace('-', '+');
        switch (originalData.Length % 4)
        {
            case 2: originalDataSanitized += "=="; break;
            case 3: originalDataSanitized += "="; break;
        }
        byte[] bytesToVerify = Convert.FromBase64String(originalDataSanitized);

                    var signatureSanitized = signature
    .Replace('_', '/').Replace('-', '+');
            switch (signature.Length % 4)
            {
                case 2: signatureSanitized += "=="; break;
                case 3: signatureSanitized += "="; break;
            }
            byte[] signedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(signatureSanitized);
             var token = (String)context.Variables["api.NamedValue.corrigoKey"];

// Certifcate verfication logic is not supported as few namespaces not supported by Azure APIM.
                   return "true";
                 }" />
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
</policies>


You can use the certificate as your key
Step 1: Upload the Certificate

Navigate to the Azure Portal:
Open the Azure portal.
Go to your API Management service instance.

Upload the Certificate:

Navigate to Certificates under the Security section.
Click on + Add to upload your public certificate.
Provide a name and upload the certificate file (usually .cer or
.pem).

Next - use a policy as below
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <validate-jwt header-name="Authorization" require-scheme="Bearer" failed-validation-httpcode="401" failed-validation-error-message="Unauthorized">
            <issuer-signing-keys>
                <key certificate-id="my-rsa-cert" /> <!-- signing key specified by certificate ID -->
            </issuer-signing-keys>
            <audiences>
                <audience>https://api.yourdomain.com</audience> <!-- expected audience of the token -->
            </audiences>
            <issuers>
                <issuer>http://contoso.com/</issuer> <!-- expected issuer of the token -->
            </issuers>
        </validate-jwt>
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error> 
</policies>

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/validate-jwt-policy#examples

Our token is not a standard JWT token. It is an OAuth custom token. All inbuilt policy supports only JWT tokens. It doesn't work for our scenarios.
